# Does setting Sprite alpha color component to a value < 1 have a performance impact?

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity3d-2dtools

I always thought that using transparent sprites will have performance impact, but using overdraw scene mode in Unity, I see that there is the same overdraw if I use an opaque sprite, or a sprite with alpha < 1.

Am I wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default shaders for Unity.2D and Unity.UI draws everything (including opaque sprites) as transparent geometry, unless you use a material with an opaque shader.

**Update 1:**

This is an opaque shader that I wrote for minimizing overdraw, but don't expect that it works in every situation. The opaque geometry will be renderer first and the transparent geometry on top.

```
Shader "Custom/Opaque UI"
 {  
    Properties
    {
        _Color("Color", Color) = (1,1,1,1)
        _MainTex ("Texture", 2D) = "white" {}
    }

    SubShader
    {
        Tags 
        { 
            "RenderType" = "Opaque" 
        }

        Pass
        {
            CGPROGRAM
            #pragma vertex vert
            #pragma fragment frag
            #include "UnityCG.cginc"

            sampler2D _MainTex;
            half3 _Color;

            struct v2f {
                float4 pos : SV_POSITION;
                float2 uv : TEXCOORD0;
                float4 color : COLOR;
            };

            float4 _MainTex_ST;

            v2f vert (appdata_full v)
            {
                v2f o;
                o.pos = mul (UNITY_MATRIX_MVP, v.vertex);
                o.uv = TRANSFORM_TEX (v.texcoord, _MainTex);
                o.color = v.color;
                return o;
            }

            half4 frag (v2f i) : COLOR
            {
                half4 color_MainTex = tex2D (_MainTex, i.uv);
                return color_MainTex * i.color;
            }
            ENDCG
        }
    }
    FallBack "UI/Default"
 }
```

Comment: Thanks. Do you know where can I find an opaque shader for sprites?

Comment: I added mine into the answer, feel free to use it, but read my notes above it.

Comment: Thanks for sharing it. I see that it has UI in the name. Is it only for UI, or could be used for Sprites too?

Comment: It also works with SpriteRenderer (Unity 2D) and MeshRenderer (Unity 3D).